# Can chance be both the determining factor as well as that which breaks the chain of causality?

Tags: metaphysics, free-will, determinism

Chance as the determining factor in the sense that it may be the prima causa of an event or set of events. For example, you were born by accident into a rich family, and this rich family enabled you to get the best education possible. And then it breaks the chain of causality by being chance and then anything can happen. For example, you have the good education, but chance has it that you break up with the love of your life and you drop out of college and are now homeless.
Does this make logical sense? Could one say that contexts and environment are determined by chance or is that self contradictory?

Comment: Aristotle has a discussion on whether chance can be a cause, I don't recall the details of it though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question presupposes that once a chain "gets started" it has a fixed or determined path/end - **unless chance** comes by and changes it (breaks the chain).  This is not correct.
Because of "free will," individuals don't have to depend on chance to determine what path they will follow.
Chance can only make it **easier or harder** for a person to follow a desired path, but **can not force** the person to follow a particular path.  So ultimately it is **the person**, not chance, that "breaks the chain."

Answer (score 0):

That chance can be a factor is a common misconception in ordinary use. Chance is a statement about the likelihood of an effect. It is a reflection of our uncertainty about the factors, not a category of factors.

The chain of causality is not broken in any way by it, it reflects a point in the chain at which we have a degree of uncertainty about the next stage.

In a deterministic universe, this uncertainty could be resolved by investigation, in a probabilistic one, we could never resolve it no matter how much we know, but in neither case does the uncertainty itself become a cause.

To put it back into human terms as is the phraseology of your question, it is wrong to presume that a path is determined either by the person enacting some free will or chance, it is almost universally a combination of the two (in more proper terminology, factors within their apparent control and factors outside of it). Thus the chain of causality has not been broken, it simply becomes more or less predictable.

If you look at causality at a very human level the contrast you are outlining is one of intentional effects as opposed to unintentional effects. Again, chance itself is not the factor, but the degree of intention. This again is considered too polemically. Just because we intend something to happen does not mean that we caused it to happen, the factors contributing to the emergence of an effect are almost immeasurably numerous and our intention is just one.

In short, there is far less difference between the intentional education and the unintentional break-up than it seems in terms of the chain of causality.